# Continuity of $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ (except $0$)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For both cases, we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0<\epsilon$.

1. For $x>0$, I can have $0<x<\infty\Leftrightarrow -x_0<x-x_0<\infty-x_0$. To pass from $|x-x_0|<\delta$ to $-\delta<x-x_0<\delta$, I can choose $\delta=x_0$, but I would lose the rest of the right end point. Is it ok?
2. For $x<0$, it's basically the same thing. $-\infty<x<0\Leftrightarrow -\infty-x_0<x-x_0<-x_0$. I can again choose $\delta=-x_0$ tl get $x_0<x-x_0<-x_0$, but I would lose the rest of the interval.

Comment: What is meaning of "$\delta=(0,\infty)$"? $\delta$ is number in continuity definition.

Comment: @zkutch well, let's pretend that it never happened. :/

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: @AntonioJPan for $x$ positive, I should find a delta that would tell me that $-x_0<x-x_0<\infty-x_0$, for example. But I don't see how I can find that delta. Same thing for the $x<0$.

Comment: Consideration, imho, should start from $x_0$, not from $x$, and for it and $\epsilon$ then derived $\delta$.

Comment: You can choose $\delta=\frac{|0-x_0|}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer to continuity of $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$:

Let's take $x_0>0$, then obviously $\frac{x_0}{2}>0$ and for $\forall \epsilon >0$ taking it as $\delta$ finishes proof. Same for $x_0<0$.

Comment: We can actually have $\delta=|x_0|$, as I have shown. The question was kind of bizarre, I guess. I think that I don't really need to prove that a function is continuous on the largest possible interval. Thank you, nevertheless.

Comment: @Luyw. "largest" is task set by you, not by continuity definition. There we have "$\exists \delta$", so any fixed number $<x_0$ will work in place of $\delta$. Perfectionism makes life harder - no? Thanks for decision.